# MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'cinClient' is not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm kinda new to spring , I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.
I have created a html page in a spring boot application that has got multiple input. So the form looks something like this:

```html
<!-- some code -->
    <input type="text" id="cinClient" name="cinClient"    placeholder="CIN Client"  th:value="${blog!=null and blog.cinClient!=null }?${blog.cinClient}:''"  required="true">
<!-- some code -->
```

the controller's function is

```java
@PostMapping("/blogs/save")
    @ResponseBody
    public Result save(@RequestParam("cinClient") String cinClient{
Blog blog = new Blog();
        blog.setCinClient(cinClient);
if ("success".equals(saveBlogResult)) {
            return ResultGenerator.genSuccessResult("Transaction sauvegarde !");
        } else {
            return ResultGenerator.genFailResult(saveBlogResult);
        }
    }
```

When I run the Spring application and click on the form button I get the following exception on the console:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'cinClient' is not present]
```

i have tried virtually every solution i've seen on google,but the problem still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RequestParam` is used for query parameters, like: `http://localhost:8080/blogs/save?cinClient=myValue`

If you're sending a POST (like it is shown with your `@PostMapping`) without this query parameter but sending body to the request, you should receive: `public Result save(@RequestBody MyRequest request)` and this `MyRequest` class would be like:

```
public class MyRequest {
    private String cinClient;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer,unfortunately it still wont work, since i'm using my batis, it wont accept objects.
it hits me with this error 
```org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'cin_client' doesn't have a default value```

Comment: Spring MVC should receive objects... Did it enter the controller at least?

Comment: my bad i did a typo,thank you for your help.
Cheers !